# Add price to unit price when checked, minus price when unchcked

Tags: php, jquery

So i have a 'total' field at the bottom of this column.

Above this field are checkboxes, when ticked, the 'total' should update by adding the price of that checkbox, and when unticked, the price should be removed.

So something similar to http://www.tepilo.com/#packages-anc

the below code updates the price when checkbox is clicked
it does nothing when unclicked
when clicked again, it adds to the new current price

```
    $('.col-2 input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
        var attribute_name = $(this).val();
        var attribute_price = settings.wsapo_custom[0][attribute_name].price;
        var current_price_total = $(".col-2 #update-price").text();

        var new_price = parseInt(current_price_total) + parseInt(attribute_price);

        console.log(new_price);
        $(".col-2 #update-price").text(new_price);


    });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the onchange or change function in jquery will suffice here. Check if the checkbox is checked and then just change the data accordingly.

Demo on JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/t9d04oeb/

Code:

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var actual = parseInt($('p').text());        
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
           actual+= 100; 
    else
        actual-=100;
    $('p').text(actual);
});
```

And feel free to read the docs about this function: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: thanks for your comment, i've seen the code works perfectly fine in that fiddle. but for some reason its still not working

here is the scenario

original figure is 195
when i check the checkbox, it becomes 295 - (thats expected)
when i uncheck it, it becomes 95 - this is not expected and i have no idea whats going on

Comment: Well this is probably because it's subtraction 100 from 195, and not 100 from 295..